# Using delete and the sed command

Tags: linux, sed

My /etc/aliases file needs editing but since I have the  same file on over 100 hosts I want to just script it and put it to work.  I have several alias entries and in one of them I want to remove the user along with the comma separator, like this:

```
alias_name1:    name1@example.com,name2@example.com,name3@example.com
alias_name2:    name1@example.com,name2@example.com,name3@example.com
```

So if I want to remove just ",name2@example.com" in "alias_name1" but not "alias_name2" how can I do that as the only example I have now is either remove the string from the entire file or remove the string from a specific line # in the file and since some of the files have a different number of lines that won't work either.

Comment: Have you considered using revision control? Have you considered augtool (augeas)? The 2nd can be used to edit config files.

Answer (score 1):

> to remove just `",name2@example.com"` in `"alias_name1"` but not
>   `"alias_name2"`

**`sed`** approach:

```
sed -E '/^alias_name1/ s/,name2@example\.com(,?)/\1/' /etc/aliases
```

The trick with the 1st captured group `(...)` will also cover cases when `,name2@example.com` figures at the end of the line or in the middle.

---

The output:

```
alias_name1:    name1@example.com,name3@example.com
alias_name2:    name1@example.com,name2@example.com,name3@example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You can preface a `sed` subsitution command with a search parameter:

```
sed '/search_string/ s/remove_string//'
```

The above command will operate only on lines that match the `/search_string/` regexp, substituting a null string for what was the `remove_string` match.